# Where can I submit request for new features in the C# language?

Tags: c#

I know Microsoft has a forum similar to uservoice.com for feature and bug submissions, but it has slipped my mind and my google-fu is fail this afternoon. Then I thought... hey, what a great question for Stack Overflow! So:

Where can I go to submit official requests for new features of the C# language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GitHub is the correct place to lodge these requests. Raise them as GitHub issues.

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang

Answer (score 18):

GitHub Issues:

- [C# language](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang)
- [VB language](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang)
- [C# cross cutting VB](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang)
- [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) discussions on the Rosyln compiler (only)
- [CoreFX](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/) This includes things like System.Collections, System.IO for .NET Core (.NET Core 2.0)
- [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues) This covers RyuJIT, GC and mscorlib for .NET Core (.NET Core 2.0)
- [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/home/issues) This is for ASP.NET Core (.NET Core 2.0)
- ASP.NET 4.7 - unknown

Historical places not for current discussion:

- <strike>[Roslyn C# Language Design forum](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/5998/c-language-design)</strike>
- <strike>[Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) discussions on C# 6.0, C# 7.0 and beyond</strike>

There is also the [Visual Studio Uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30931-languages-c) for requests pertaining to Visual Studio specifically

Answer (score 6):

<del>https://connect.microsoft.com/</del>

Update: Connect has been retired. [This GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) is now the place to add suggestions.

Comment: I would never for any reason waste the effort to post the bone yard that is connect. Microsoft needs to terminate that site.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic For .NET development, they have effectively terminated it now and are asking users to post to the relevant [dotnet Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/). So your answer is now actually the correct one. :-)

Comment: @DanAtkinson i posted something to the aspnet repo and was told it's not for that asp.net

Answer (score 4):

<del>[Here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30931-languages-c) is the official user voice channel for suggestions and ideas on the C# language.</del>

Update: The UserVoice channel has been retired. [This GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) is now the place to add suggestions.